# Вывод данных из input в таблицу

Tags: input

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Нужно при нажатии кнопки Add добавить в таблицу данные из инпутов. Я уже совсем запутался...

```js
function insertRow(id) {
  var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  var row = document.createElement("tr")
  var td1 = document.createElement("td")
  td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1"))
  var td2 = document.createElement("td")
  td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("checkbox"))
  var td3 = document.createElement("td")
  td3.appendChild(document.getElementById("addid")[0].value)
  var td4 = document.createElement("td")
  td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1"))
  var td5 = document.createElement("td")
  td5.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1.99"))
  var td6 = document.createElement("td")
  td6.appendChild(document.createTextNode("action1"))
  var td7 = document.createElement("td")
  td7.appendChild(document.createTextNode("action2"))
  row.appendChild(td1);
  row.appendChild(td2);
  row.appendChild(td3);
  row.appendChild(td4);
  row.appendChild(td5);
  row.appendChild(td6);
  row.appendChild(td7);
  tbody.appendChild(row);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Shopping list</li>
    <li>Done</li>
    <li>Deleted</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <h1 class="h1">Shopping List</h1>
  <hr class="hr">
  <input type="text" id="addid" placeholder="Add items ti you Shopping List">
  <input placeholder="Quant." type="text">
  <input placeholder="Price" type="text">
  <button type="button" onclick="insertRow('myTable');return false;">Add</button>
</div>
<div class="table">
  <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Price $</td>
        <td>Action1</td>
        <td>Action2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените строчку

```
td3.appendChild(document.getElementById("addid")[0].value)
```

на

```
td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("addid").value))
```

*Update*

Желание "понять, а не бездумно делать" достойно всяческого уважения. Посему:

Первое. `document.getElementById` возвращает DOM элемент (или `null`, если не найдет), а не массив, поэтому свойство `value` надо брать от этого возвращаемого значения (без `[0]`).

Второе. Метод `appendChild` в качестве параметра ожидает DOM элемент (а не строку), поэтому `value` из первого пункта надо завернуть в `document.createTextNode()`.

*От автора вопроса:*

Вот этот кусочек:

```
function insertRow(id) { 
  var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]‌​;
```

Зачем у функции указывается параметр "id"? Зачем объявляется tbody и какую функцию эта строка выполняет? Каким образом должен выглядеть скрипт, если я захочу его выделить в отдельный .js? (в таком виде как он есть - ругается).

*Ответы:*

Параметр `id` используется в качестве уникального условия для нахождения элемента `table` с атрибутом `id="myTable"`.

Переменная `tbody` - DOM элемент (часть таблицы) , который содержит в себе строки таблицы. Посмотрите на последнюю строчку функции - именно в `tbody` добавляется вновь созданный `row`.

Какой скрипт Вы хотите выделить в отдельный .js? Всю функцию? Покажите, как Вы это делаете. Эта функция идеально подходит для выноса во внешний .js файл.

Comment: Отлично, работает! А можете немного пояснить почему именно так, чтобы я на будущее понимал а не бездумно делал? Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо.С большего осмыслил. Еще пару вопросов в догонку, если можно.
Вот этот кусочек:
function insertRow(id) {
var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

Зачем у функции указывается параметр "id"?
Зачем объявляется tbody и какую функцию эта строка выполняет?
Каким образом должен выглядеть скрипт, если я захочу его выделить в отдельный .js? (в таком виде как он есть - ругается). Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Всю функцию полностью выношу в отдельный .js файл.
Но в таком случае на все строки, где присутствует "document" ругается ошибкой "document is not defined"

Comment: @TheHateInMe Что-то здесь не то. Пора задавать другой вопрос.

Comment: Да, это уж совсем другая история. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @TheHateInMe Пожалуйста. Слева от ответа - значок "галочка".